# Using Java to interact with the Windows OS

Tags: java, powershell

Which method is the best way to query and return data from Windows OS using java? I have used the *exec()* method to query calls to the command line, but that can be a pain when writing complex OS call queries.

Would PowerShell be the recommended way to query data from the Windows OS using Java? If so how can I go about it in Java?

Examples of Windows OS call queries would be from returning *host details, memory(RAM) details*, to *closing and opening logical ports (security reasons)*, and much more that can't be done via internal Java.

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: I think you want something to do with the System.getProperty(String); function, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that is the same as using the exec() method. But I will look into that method.
Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html)

It is a robust and reliable library to execute external processes from Java-code.

Here is [the javadoc for this library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems legit. I take alot at that.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

hey i think this might help

```
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```